# laravel 4 multiple DB connection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Playing around with laravel 4 and was wondering if there is a way to run migrations on different connections, so if I have as default:

```
'sqlsrv' => array(
    'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
    'host'     => '192.168.1.11\SQLEXPRESS',
    'database' => 'database1',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'password',
    'prefix'   => '',
    ),
```

But I want a different migration to go here:

```
'sqlsrv2' => array(
    'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
    'host'     => '192.168.1.11\SQLEXPRESS',
    'database' => 'database2',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'password',
    'prefix'   => '',
    ),
```

I have no doubt there is a way to do it, but I'm not finding it in the docs. :)

Comment: Besides specifying your connection directly into the migration like `Schema::connection('foo')->create...` your other option is to extend the Migration and specify it there. I agree it sucks that you can't specify the connection during the migrate command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs at http://laravel.com/docs/schema#creating-and-dropping-tables

To specify which connection the schema operation should take place on, use the `Schema::connection` method:

```
Schema::connection('foo')->create('users', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

Comment: Holy crap I looked at that 10 times and it just now makes sense.. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

It worked with

```
php artisan migrate --env=local --database=my_connection_name
```

but it has ignored

```
Schema::connection('my_connection_name').
```